# maven-jaxb2-plugin fails when running downloaded purchase order sample

Tags: maven, jaxb

I downloaded the sample project `maven-jaxb2-plugin-sample-po-0.12.2-maven-src.zip` and it fails with an error as shown below:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.0:generate (default) @ maven-jaxb2-plugin-sample-po-maven ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.11 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2.XJC2Mojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener
```

This error is quite strange since all I doing is just running  mvn clean install

Does anyone know what's going on or seen this error before?

Comment: Update: It fails in STS Version: 3.7.0.RELEASE. Any ideas why it is failing in STS?

Answer (score 1):

`maven-jaxb2-plugin` requires to be executed by a jdk and not a jre.

This does work

```
set JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92
mvn package
```

This does **not** work

```
set JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92
mvn package
```

When the plugin is used in Eclipse/STS, then Eclipse/STS must be started using a JDK. [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example)

Answer (score 0):

I did face similar issue. I did resolve it by making changes in pom.xml as suggested at https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-a-Specific-JAXB-Version 
My plugin configuration is.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb22-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
          <schemaIncludes>
            <include>*.wsdl</include>
          </schemaIncludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```